# Passing multiple objects from children to main thread

Tags: java, multithreading

i've this problem, I've a Multithreaded server running. here it's the code:

```
 ServerSocket serverSocket=null; // defining a server socket to listen data
         Socket clientSocket = null; // defining a client socket to send data
        final int port=8080; 
        int i=0;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port); // Opening a server socket to listen for client calls
            System.out.println("Server started.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Port already in use.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        while (true) {

            try {

                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); //binding server socket to client socket incoming call and accepting call
                System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + clientSocket);
                i=i+1;
                Thread t = new Thread(new newClientHandler(clientSocket, NodePRs[1]),"thread"+i); //Create a new thread to handle the single call coming from one client
                System.out.println("Thread "+t.getName()+" is starting");
                t.start(); //Starting the run method contained in newCLIENTHandler class

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Error in connection attempt.");
            }
            }//end while
```

All that i need is to let the children thread (opened every time a client request come) pass (like a function return) 4 variables when the children thread die. The newClientHandler code is this:

```
        public class newClientHandler implements Runnable {


     private final static int FILE_SIZE=6022386;


     private Socket clientSocket;
     private PaillierPrivateKey PrivKey;
     ServerSocket servSock;
     BigInteger[] msg = null;
     BigInteger preamble = null;
     int bytesRead;
     int current = 0;
     DataOutputStream dos = null;
     BufferedReader dis = null;
     FileOutputStream fos = null;
     BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
     int msgtype=-1;
     int num_of_rx_cnks=-1;


    public newClientHandler(Socket client, PaillierPrivateKey PR) {
        this.clientSocket = client;
        this.PrivKey = PR;

    }

//I CAN RECEIVE 3 TYPES OF MESSAGES: SHARE, THE ENCRYPTED PASSWORD, THE 4 PDMS
    public void run() {
        try{

             ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
             ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
             preamble = (BigInteger) ois.readObject();


             System.out.println("Received Preamble is:"+preamble);
             oos.writeObject("Received preamble");
             msg =(BigInteger[]) ois.readObject();
             System.out.println("Received Message is:"+msg+"\n"+msg[0]+"\n"+msg[2]);



             String sPlain = Utilities.bigIntegerToString(preamble);
             String[] splitArr=Pattern.compile("-").split(sPlain);
             msgtype=Integer.parseInt(splitArr[0]);
             num_of_rx_cnks=Integer.parseInt(splitArr[1]);
             System.out.println("Message type: "+msgtype+"\n"+"Number of received cnks: "+num_of_rx_cnks);


             //a questo punto ho i miei 29 biginteger. Li devo sistemare uno accanto all'altro e rimettere nel file. 



             switch(msgtype){

             case 1: //Share received

                 System.out.println("Received the share");
                 for(int i=0;i<num_of_rx_cnks;i++){
                        String name = new String();
                        if(i<9){
                            name="Cyph2"+".00"+(i+1);
                        }
                        if(i>8){
                            name="Cyph2"+".0"+(i+1);
                        }
                        Utilities.newBigIntegerToFile(msg[i], name);
                    }

                    Utilities.retrieveShare(PrivKey, 2,"myShare");
                    int l, w;
                    BigInteger v, n, shares, combineSharesConstant;
                    BigInteger[]  viarray=new BigInteger[5];
                    PaillierPrivateThresholdKey[] res = null;
                    try {  
                        FileReader File= new FileReader("myShare");
                        BufferedReader buf=new BufferedReader(File);
                        String line=buf.readLine();
                        l = Integer.parseInt(line.split(":")[1]);

                        line = buf.readLine();
                        w = Integer.parseInt(line.split(":")[1]);

                        line = buf.readLine();
                        v = new BigInteger(line.split(":")[1]);

                        line = buf.readLine();
                        n = new BigInteger(line.split(":")[1]);

                        line = buf.readLine();
                        combineSharesConstant = new BigInteger(line.split(":")[1]);

                        line = buf.readLine();
                        shares = new BigInteger(line.split(":")[1]);

                        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
                        line = buf.readLine();
                        viarray[i] = BigInteger.ZERO;
                        }

                    SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
                    PaillierPrivateThresholdKey result = new PaillierPrivateThresholdKey(n, l, combineSharesConstant, w, v, 
                            viarray, shares, 2, rnd.nextLong());//il 2 qua è il nodeID
                    }catch(IOException e){
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                 break;

             case 2: // Session Secret received

                 break;

             case 3: //PDM received

                 break;


             }//end switch





        }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println(ioe);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
            System.out.println(cnfe);
        }finally {
            try{
                  if (dis != null) dis.close();
                  if (dos != null) dos.close();
                  if (clientSocket!=null) clientSocket.close();
                }catch (IOException e){
                    System.out.println(e);
                    }
            }



        }
}
```

I'd like to pass l, w, v, n and so on to let my main thread do some processing. How can i modify my code to do it?

Comment: First, **give your variables good names**. `l`, `w`, `v` and `n` are not good names. Second, declaring things equal to `null` then reassigning is a really bad habit. Assign things when you declare them, and declare them `final` so that you break this habit. Finally, don't spawn a `new Thread` for every request - this is slow and error prone. Consider a [`Selector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html). To answer your main question - why does the `main` thread care?

Comment: For the first things, thx for the hints, i'll modify. By the fact i'm auto-educated i miss some things, so thx for pointing that out :) .

The fact is that: i'll have to run this server on 5 nodes talking to each other in a MANET environment, and 4 nodes has to communicate with the others, so i've to open a children thread for every client request to let the main thread be free to receive data from other clients. For this i've to pass those variables to my main thread, and then pass em again to a processing thread to let it do some processing like encrypt and decrypt messages and texts

Answer (score 0):

Use a Callable instead of a Runnable.

Bundle the 4 variables into a class and implement `Callable<YourNewClass>`.  Run your callable with an executor and you'll get the results in a `Future<YourNewClass>`.

Comment: i'd have to modify all of my code, isn't there a way to like pass an object like the PaillierPrivateThresholdKey result. Like declaring a null PaillierPrivateThresholdKey in the main thread, then pass it to the thread and then have it modified in main? (with proper sinchronization)

Comment: You can store your results anywhere you like.  You can put then in the main object used by the main thread.  However, I'm not sure how the main thread will know when they're ready.  For that, you'd need to make more significant changes to your code.

Comment: ok, thank you very much. I'll try to understand what a callable is and modify my work :) rly appreciated